# Not able to get ionic content in view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am unable to get my content and header title in page in Ionic. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Expecting to have a bar-positive header with Left and Right button and some content, but its coming totally **blank** no JS error in console too.

**index.html**

```
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

**app.js** -

```
  .state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',    
    views: {
      'signup': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html'
      }
    }
  })
```

**signup.html** -

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="left" class="bar-positive">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Left Button</button>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button">Right Button</button>
  </div>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  Some content! Some content! Some content! Some content! Some content! Some content! Some content! Some content! 
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Your state definition says that your `signup.html` will be loaded when your go this state explicitly by hitting the `#/signup` url.

Comment: @Arkantos I am hitting the URL http://localhost:8100/#/signup in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state config for `signup` looks for a named view called `signup` (under `views` object) but your `<ion-nav-view>` is not a named one. You can fix this by adding `name` attribute to `<ion-nav-view>` like below.

```
<ion-nav-view name="signup"></ion-nav-view>
```

(or) you can remove the named views definition from your state if you're certain that there's always one view that needs to be updated.

```
.state('signup', {
    url: '/signup',    
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html'
  });
```

Comment: definitely I need to remove the named views as I need to create separate login, dashboard pages as well ...thx +1 I will accept this as well :)

Comment: It actually depends on your use case. If you wish to update multiple sections on your page at once then you can use named views.